# Spyder doesn't launch from Anaconda on MacBook

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda to start coding in Python. However, after installing, the moment I launch Spyder I get the error "Python quit unexpectedly" error. I have tried running "conda update --all" and even reinstalling anaconda but no help.

Just for a sanity check, I looked up python version in the Terminal it is 3.7.6. If anyone can suggest a way to fix it'll be most helpful.

```
Entire Problem detail & system configuration below
Process:               python [6870]
Path:                  /opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python
Identifier:            python
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [6869]
Responsible:           python [6870]
User ID:               501

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x00000001075b144b npy_cpu_supports + 139
1   _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x000000010742f0fe InitOperators + 94
2   _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x000000010742dc00 PyInit__multiarray_umath + 160
3   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bc3c1d _PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec + 557
4   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bc3033 _imp_create_dynamic + 243
5   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
6   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
7   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
8   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
9   com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
10  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
11  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
12  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
13  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
14  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
15  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
16  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
17  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
18  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
19  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
20  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
21  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
22  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
23  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
24  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
25  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
26  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
27  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
28  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
29  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
30  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
31  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
32  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
33  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
34  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
35  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
36  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
37  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
38  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
39  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
40  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
41  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
42  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
43  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
44  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
45  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
46  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
47  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
48  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
49  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
50  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
51  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b809d5 builtin___import__ + 149
52  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a59388 PyCFunction_Call + 168
53  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
54  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
55  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
56  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
57  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
58  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
59  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a577c7 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 231
60  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
61  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
62  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbbd03 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 931
63  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
64  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
65  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
66  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
67  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
68  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
69  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
70  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
71  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
72  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
73  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
74  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
75  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
76  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
77  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
78  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
79  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
80  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
81  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
82  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
83  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
84  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
85  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
86  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b809d5 builtin___import__ + 149
87  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a59388 PyCFunction_Call + 168
88  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
89  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
90  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
91  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
92  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
93  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
94  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a577c7 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 231
95  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
96  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
97  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbbd03 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 931
98  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
99  com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
100 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
101 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
102 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
103 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
104 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
105 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
106 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
107 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
108 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
109 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
110 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
111 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
112 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
113 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
114 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
115 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
116 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
117 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
118 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
119 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
120 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
121 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b809d5 builtin___import__ + 149
122 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a59388 PyCFunction_Call + 168
123 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
124 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
125 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
126 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
127 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
128 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
129 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a577c7 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 231
130 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
131 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
132 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbbd03 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 931
133 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
134 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
135 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
136 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
137 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
138 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
139 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
140 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
141 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
142 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
143 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
144 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
145 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
146 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
147 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
148 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
149 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
150 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
151 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
152 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
153 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
154 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
155 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
156 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b809d5 builtin___import__ + 149
157 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58bd8 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 392
158 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95de2 call_function + 306
159 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
160 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
161 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
162 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
163 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
164 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
165 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
166 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
167 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
168 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
169 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
170 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
171 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
172 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
173 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
174 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
175 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
176 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
177 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
178 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
179 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
180 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
181 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
182 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
183 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
184 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
185 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
186 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
187 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
188 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
189 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
190 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
191 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
192 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
193 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
194 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
195 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
196 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
197 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
198 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
199 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
200 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
201 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
202 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
203 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
204 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbc798 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
205 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b809d5 builtin___import__ + 149
206 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a59388 PyCFunction_Call + 168
207 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
208 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
209 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
210 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
211 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
212 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
213 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a577c7 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 231
214 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5a978 object_vacall + 248
215 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5ab83 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
216 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105bbbd03 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 931
217 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b91919 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37497
218 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
219 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b81e9b builtin_exec + 347
220 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a57c0f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
221 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a5931d PyCFunction_Call + 61
222 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93d9d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46845
223 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b8746e _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
224 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a58a03 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
225 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
226 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92b92 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42226
227 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
228 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
229 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b92afc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42076
230 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105a582d5 function_code_fastcall + 117
231 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b95d67 call_function + 183
232 com.continuum.python            0x0000000105b93ad4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46132
```

Comment: Can you run your Anaconda environment `python` from the terminal? Or is it just `spyder` that crashes?

Comment: Opening terminal from Anaconda root allows me to run python.. its just that when i launch Spyder it refuses to start always giving me the same "Python quit unexpectedly" error.